# Поиск по полю добавленному в сериализаторе

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему. Мне нужно организовать поиск по имени чата. Но имя чата создаётся в момент сериализации объекта.

```
name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_chat_name')
```

"SearchFilter" работает с queryset, но queryset не имеет этого поля. Потому как это поле добавляется в момент сериализации.

```
class ChatList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ChatSerializers
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Chat.objects.filter(chatusers__user=user)

class ChatSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_chat_name')

    def get_chat_name(self, chat):
        if chat.type == 0:
            queryset = ChatUsers.objects.exclude(user = self.context['request'].user).get(chat=chat.pk)
            user_name = queryset.user.get_full_name()
            if user_name:
                return user_name
            else:
                return queryset.user.username
        if chat.type == 1:
            return chat.name`
```

Нужно найти адекватное решение этой проблемы. Есть идеи? Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Поправил. Спасибо

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста сам метод get_chat_name

Comment: Я думаю этот метод не имеет значение так как он всего лишь подставляет определённые данные в зависимости от типа чата. 
Добавил в основной текст вопроса

Comment: Зная то, что именно вы делаете внутри этого метода, можно придумать хорошую альтернативу, для решения вашей проблемы.

Comment: Вас понял. Я так же задумываюсь об этом. Я думаю эта тема будет полезной для многих.  Если у вас есть идеи буду рад их выслушать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут вам не поможет стандартная фильтрация, придётся писать свою. В `APIView` есть свойство `query_params`, которое содержит в себе все параметры `GET` запроса (post не пробовал, возможно тоже). В целом всё [описано в документации](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters), вам нужно переопределить метод `get_queryset` и отфильтровать нужные вам результаты примерно так:

```
qs = Chat.objects.all()
query = self.query_params.get('q')
if query:
    qs = qs.filter(Q(chat__type=1) | Q(chat__name__like=query), Q(chat__type=0) | Q(chat__user__first_name__like=query))
```

Comment: А что если изменять имя чата на уровне не сериализатора, а модели?

Comment: @AlexIvanchik у  вас поиск идёт на уровне бд, поэтому разницы нет в сериализаторе генерировать название чата или в модели